# Not able to scan barcode android application

Tags: android, barcode, zxing, barcode-scanner

Iam trying to scan following image with Zxing barcode scanner

[image]

Sometime it is able to scan and for most of the times it is not able to scan. Camera in the phone iam testing has fixed focus.

How can i improve the reliability so that iam able to scan any one of the barcodes at a time.

All three barcodes are same!

Comment: In this article [Not able to read 2D data matrix in Image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28115331/not-able-to-read-2d-data-matrix-in-image), it says that it became successful by arranging the barcode extracted using the Image class at the center of the image. Rather than letting you read as many as 3 at a time, how about cutting out one by one?

Comment: @kunif do you know how can Zxing algorithm can be modified to not just scan the barcode in the center of the image, i mean to be able to scan the barcode on the sides also? I tried changing the algorithm in WhiteRectangleDetector class to start finding the borders of the barcode from the edges of the image, instead of center but with no luck.

Comment: I'm sorry, I am not familiar with this field and I am just searching. I found these articles, which may be helpful. [ZXing: Finding the bounding rectangle of Barcode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21544324/zxing-finding-the-bounding-rectangle-of-barcode), [Detecting (not decoding!) datamatrix (rectangle) regions in an image](http://answers.opencv.org/question/119161/detecting-not-decoding-datamatrix-rectangle-regions-in-an-image/), [Scan multiple barcodes with ZXing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11628373/scan-multiple-barcodes-with-zxing)